# How do I exclude a monitoring server from ganglia reports?

Tags: cluster-computing, monitoring, ganglia

I'm running ganglia in EC2 and reporting works well. I'm running gmetad to monitor a database cluster from an admin reporting instance that is a centralized dashboard for all our systems. I don't want this instance to be included in the monitoring. In the admin gmond.conf, I've set:

```
mute = yes
```

But this only makes the web front-end show the host as dead. In the admin gmetad.conf, I have the data_source set to:

```
data_source "cluster" ec2-X-X-X-X.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

(with ec2-X-X-X-X.compute-1.amazonaws.com being the ec2 hostname of the admin instance)

I thought setting `mute=yes` would remove it from the reports and gstat, but both still show the admin host (localhost) as dead.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the `host_dmax` attribute to a value other than 0 in your gmond.conf file.

For me the mute Ganglia host shows up initially (after restart) but then disappears after the time I've set for `host_dmax`. It's unclear why the host shows up in the first place after a restart even though `mute` is set to yes.

The `cleanup_threshold` attribute may also affect the time it takes for the host to disappear.

This is covered in the [Ganglia wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ganglia/wiki/Gmond%203.1.x%20General%20Configuration):

> The `host_dmax` value is an integer with units in seconds. When set to zero (0), gmond will never delete a host from its list even when a remote host has stopped reporting. If `host_dmax` is set to a positive number then gmond will flush a host after it has not heard from it for `host_dmax` seconds. By the way, dmax means "delete max".
>
> The `cleanup_threshold` is the minimum amount of time before gmond will cleanup any hosts or metrics where tn > dmax a.k.a. expired data.

Comment: Thanks very much. What would you recommend as settings for these values? I assume the `host_dmax` should be fairly high so that I can be aware of legitimate failures.

Comment: @DaveStern That depends on your scenario. Set up an alerting facility (Nagios is common to use) to quickly become aware of failures. If a host disappears from the web interface you will still have its history data collected by gmetad in its RRD database. You can substitute the `h` parameter in ganglia-web graph URLs with the hostname of the desired node to graph its data and see what happened.